# DC/OS single-node master does not recover manual reboot

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I've already setup a single-master single-slave DC/OS 1.9 for test purpose. I did reboot master node and it failed to restart itself (Server is up, but none of dcos-* services are running). Is there any procedure to recover my master? I did find slave recovery in the docs, but there was nothing about master.

Please tell me how should i recover my master.

Comment: Any information in logs?

Comment: Hi, there was no log no where, Unfortunately even the slave recovery which is documented in DC/OS docs fails and doesn't work, I finally found a workaround which we should manually daemon-reload services and run all dcos-* service one-by-one (Worse is that order of running is important, for example DNS services should run first), I created an ansible for it which may help, I have gathered a few other solutions for other problems related to DC/OS, Is it ok to ask some questions and answer them myself in stackoverflow?

Comment: logs can be found by running `journalctl -xe`